# Is it possible to show I got non-authoritative answer from which server?

Tags: dns, nslookup

I am not very clear with how the non-authoritative answer is given.

For some domains I get this kind of results:

```
root@localhost:~# nslookup
> set query=ns
> foo.org
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
foo.org       nameserver = dns5.name-services.com.
foo.org       nameserver = dns3.name-services.com.
foo.org       nameserver = dns4.name-services.com.
foo.org       nameserver = dns2.name-services.com.
foo.org       nameserver = dns1.name-services.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Even When I use querytype=soa, the Authoritative Answer is blank. Why does that happen?

And as I understand it, Non-Authoritative means it's the cache result from some server, probably my ISP. I was not sure, when I query NS, Non-Authoritative NS result is the NS of the cache server (ISP) or authoritative server?

Then I checked with a online tool called simpledns, the dnsX.name-services.com ns seems to be the Authoritative Answer NS. Why is it showing in the Non-Authoritative Answer? And if they actually are authoritative NS, is it possible to show the non-authoritative server NS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non-Authoritative means it's the cache result from some server

Yes. Authoritative answers only come from servers which directly host the data; non-authoritative answers come from caches/proxies.

> probably my ISP

No. In your example, the address of the cache server is `8.8.8.8` (as shown above in the program's output); it is a Google Public DNS server.

In nslookup you can use the `server` command to direct queries to some other server, be it caching or authoritative.

> Even When I use querytype=soa, the Authoritative Answer is blank. Why does that happen?

SOA records are not special in that regard. They're hosted by the same servers as the rest of the zone. If they're queried through a caching/proxy server, that response is non-authoritative because of where it was queried, not because of the record type.

To get an authoritative answer, you need to send the query to a server that is authoritative for that domain. The NS response you got tells you which servers are.

> I was not sure, when I query NS, Non-Authoritative NS result is the NS of the cache server (ISP) or authoritative server?

The cache server itself is never part of the results; it gives you unaltered data. So the NS records are the same that the cache server itself got from some authoritative server (i.e. they come from the actual domain, and aren't autogenerated by the cache), and they also point to an authoritative server.

> And if they actually are authoritative NS, is it possible to show the non-authoritative server NS?

NS records in a domain always point to authoritative servers for their domain. That's literally what they are for.

Domains don't generally *have* designated non-authoritative servers, because if they had one, then such a server would kinda become authoritative by definition... "Non-authoritative" responses just mean *everything else*, i.e. responses produced by any cache DNS server around the net.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, if I can confirm that I understand it correctly. 1. the NS from Non-authoritative answer is authoritative but saved on cache server. 2. There is no way to track which cache server send me the answer since domains are related to authoritative servers only.

Comment: 1) Yes, the NS points to authoritative servers, and it also comes from authoritative servers. 2) Of course there is – it's the same server that you sent the query to, and its address is shown right above the actual response. The 8.8.8.8 is the cache server you're using.

Comment: About 2), yes, I am sorry about the 8.8.8.8 config, it's a bit off my actual situation and misleading. I usually use the router/modem's gateway (192.168.1.1) as the DNS server, and it will send to ISP's cache server I guess. I can see 192.168.1.1 on nslookup results, but I am not sure what happens after. I'm experiencing some dns query REFUSED situation, if I query again immediately, the results show, but after a while, it refuses again. Seems to be some cache problem on the cache server to me.

Comment: In that case, for normal answers you would have to check the configuration of 192.168.1.1 in some other way – there's indeed no DNS built-in tool to know what further caches hide behind it. For REFUSED though, I strongly suspect it's generated by the router/modem's own cache. Does the router have `tcpdump` available?

Comment: That's the frustrating part, the router/modem is locked by ISP and requires some SU account in order to look inside. I just wrote a script to query top 1000 website with router's gateway as dns server and with 8.8.8.8, the later one got no refused at all, I think I'll call my ISP. Thank you very much for the info, that's so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that 8.8.8.8, which is the server you asked, isn't authoritative for the domain. Consecutively you'd have to ask name-services.com for an answer.

See also [DNS - NSLOOKUP what is the meaning of the non-authoritative answer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/413124/dns-nslookup-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-non-authoritative-answer) on ServerFault.